# What is the best/standard way to define a web service interface (inheritance/overloading)?

Tags: java, web-services, axis

What is the best/standard way to define a web service interface?

For example,

I have two class Car and Bus both of them extends Vehicle.

If I want to expose a create method for Car and Bus I have following options -

1. public void create(Vehicle v);
2. public void create(String type, Vehicle v);
3. public void create(Car c); and public void create(Bus b);
4. public void createCar(Vehicle v); and public void createBus(Vehicle v);
5. public void createCar(Car c); and public void createBus(Bus b);

EDIT---------------------------------

My main concern is of the above 5 options what is the standard way for a web service API. What is standard for java coding may not be standard for a webservice.

Comment: Could you expand on your question, please?

Comment: He wants to know which option he should use. (i think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in the standard way then none of those is.
Web services do not support operation overloading and it is prohibited in WS BP Profile
[WS BP](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html)

```
4.5.3 Distinctive Operations

Operation name overloading in a wsdl:portType is disallowed by the Profile.
```

This actually makes sense since the message mode (doc/lit) expects the operation name as the root of the message payload to do the dispatching.
Additionally, you are talking about OO concepts but web services standards are meant as an integration technology (not bind to specific languages or platforms).
In any case if you are expected to do that, you can implement overloading via tweeking at annotations and in your case, IMHO I think the best option would be `2` so that the consumer knows how to downcast it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code follows OO concepts and I felt it may not be correct for webservice that is why raised the doubts. This means that I write a wrapper webservice and expose the option 2 method.

Comment: @Sharad:You mean which option to use?As already said you can use (2) and depending on type create corresponding object.Alternativelly you could also use (5)

Comment: @user384706 Sorry to be not accurate in asking the question. In your answer you mentioned none of the option I have mentioned are Standard way so what is the standard way?

Comment: Web services is a means for integration and not an implementation technology.They serve as a communication channel between 2 distinct processes (any platforms).So OO concepts are not applicable;per definition any client written in any language (non-OO included)should be able to communicate with the WS.The best approach is to make the services mere transports of data and not try to reuse business classes and expose them.I am not sure if you are allowed to do that e.g. expose a service that accepts some data object to be passed along to a module that will decide if it is a Car or a Bus.

Comment: The data object will not be a Vehicle or a Car or a Bus.But it all depends on what you are expected to do and if you care about interoperability.

Answer (score 2):

The first one seems like the most generic one that you can use, and you just override it inside your `Car` or `Bus` class

Answer (score 1):

First of all your methods are called `create` and therefore by convention should be a kind of factory methods, therefore shouild *return* instance of Vehicle. Your methods look more like `init` since they receive instance of Vehicle, Car, Bus.

So, I'd suggest you to modify your signatures like

`Vehicle create(*some arguments*)`

Now about the reurn type. I'd suggest you to use generics based definition like

`<V extends Vehicle> V create()`

This method may be called without casting to specific Vehicle subclass.

About the arguemtns. I believe that you can use

1. String type (as you suggested)
2. Class type
3. Define special enum Vehicles {Car, Bus, Bike} and use it.

Alternatively you can (as you suggested) create several factory methods for each type of Vehicle like `createCar` and `createBus` but I dislike this method because every time you add new type of Vehicle you have to add such method.